# GDB `run` command fails with "Cannot insert breakpoint 1."

Tags: debugging, rust, gdb

#### Problem

I'm trying to debug [this Rust program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75dfb134bea4df761bde175d804c3902) using `rust-gdb`, but I can't seem to get GDB to work properly:

```
/home/a/tmp/foo(HEAD)
09/19/2021 09:57:23.114 AM> rust-gdb -q target/debug/foo
Reading symbols from target/debug/foo...
(gdb) b hello
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7a44: file src/main.rs, line 2.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a/tmp/foo/target/debug/foo
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x7a44

(gdb)
```

I also tried setting the breakpoint using `b src/main.rs:2` as well as running just `gdb` instead of the Rust wrapper `rust-gdb` both of which resulted in the same outcome. Am I doing this properly?

#### System Information

```
/home/a/tmp/foo(HEAD)
09/19/2021 09:07:48.200 AM> uname -a
Linux a 5.13.15_1 #1 SMP Fri Sep 10 16:52:33 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/home/a/tmp/foo(HEAD)
09/19/2021 09:07:51.291 AM> rustc --version
rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06)
/home/a/tmp/foo(HEAD)
09/19/2021 09:07:53.955 AM> gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working by uninstalling the installed `gdb` (which was obtained from the Nixpkgs repository) and replacing it with `gdb` from the Void Linux musl repository. I suspect the `gdb` from Nixpkgs was built with glibc and is incompatible with the compiled Rust program which was compiled to use musl instead. Usually, the Bedrock Linux userspace that I use allows me to use programs built with different C libraries together, but in this case I guess I needed GDB to be using the same C library as the thing it's trying to debug.